# Use of rowspan to group hierarchical data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to group data (using rowspan as explained [here](http://www.pdprogrammeur.com/tables-and-html5-table/)) in a table rendered with angularjs. Data is hierarchical, with `state` having many `counties` and each counties has multiple `zipcodes`. I want a table with only column for state, county, zip etc (so give a rowspan for length of the collection). I am not sure `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` can be used to achieve this. Please see the starter template [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/d6xjVHRQRbkC8RiYSl8k?p=preview)

```
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>County</th>
        <th>Zip</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat='st in states'>
        <td>{{st.name}}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

data

```
 var oh_counties = [
    {name: "Franklin", zips: [111,222,333,444,555]},
    {name: "Adams", zips: [111,222,333,444]},
    {name: "Allen", zips: [111,222,333]}
    ],
    wi_counties = [
    {name: "Dane", zips: [111]},
    {name: "Adams", zips: [111,222,333,444]}
    ]

    $scope.states = [
      {name: "OH", counties: oh_counties},
      {name: "WI", counties: wi_counties},
      ];
```

### Edit:

A handcrafted version of the desired output is here http://plnkr.co/edit/T7toND0odx6qr8mVC121?p=preview

Comment: You could show what you mean by writing some desired output.

Comment: @SimonPlus please see it here http://plnkr.co/edit/T7toND0odx6qr8mVC121?p=preview

Answer (score 22):

This is a variant of Holly Cummins' answer. The repeat is moved into the `tr` with `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to prevent the `tbody` from being repeated. Also uses a slightly different method to hide the first row.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start='st in states'>
      <th rowspan="{{st.counties.length}}">{{st.name}}</th>
      <td>{{st.counties[0].name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat='county in st.counties' ng-hide="$first">
       <td>{{county.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: For correctness, I think this should say st.counties[0].name

Comment: Great answer. Helped me a ton! I'm late to the party, but, but I rather like ng-if="!$first" to suppress the first cell in the first "following" row, because it keeps the HTML cleaner by not even having the element on the DOM in the first place :)

Comment: Agreed, that will produce better html, I just like the look on the ng-hide as the code looks a little more readable because it looks so close to saying 'hide the first'

Comment: Thanks you very much for this !

Answer (score 9):

This variant of KayakDave's answer improves the structuring by pulling the first nested row out to share the `<tr>` of the header:

```
<tbody ng-repeat='st in states'>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="{{st.counties.length}}">{{st.name}}</th>
      <td>{{county[0].name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='county in st. counties' ng-show="$index > 0">
       <td>{{county.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure.  Is something like this what you had in mind:

```
<tbody ng-repeat='st in states'>
    <td rowspan="{{st.counties.length+1}}">{{st.name}}</td>
    <tr ng-repeat='county in st.counties'>
       <td>{{county.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I kept this example simple, nested 2 deep.  But in the fiddle, below, I've got it nested 3 deep (so it includes zip).

[demo fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/SabdQmO3wtIf7ZGecLAe?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for the example. But, it is not structured properly. see it with css class applied. http://plnkr.co/edit/FqCHTodxoJSegw6CySaS?p=preview . The third column is nested within second. Also, I am not sure tr can be nested within td.

Comment: A table can be nested in a td- with a tr inside the table- which is why I approached it that way. To create the structure you've added to your question I'd write a custom directive.

Answer (score 0):

This may be usefull

```
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat='st in states'>
        <tr>
            <th >{{st.name}}</th>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr ng-repeat='county in st.counties'>
                        <td>{{county.name}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr ng-repeat='zip in county.zips'>
                                    <td>{{zip}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```