# How to display HTML table with angularJS

Tags: c#, html, angularjs

i have an object, its definition is

```
public class ExigenceResultDto
{
    public string NameExigence { get; set; }
    public Collection<string> ExigenceList { get; set; }
    public ExigenceResultDto()
    {
        ExigenceList = new Collection<string>();
    }
}
```

i want to display the result on Html page, using angularJS, the displayed table is not as i would it; it want thet every item on the result List will be displayed in a row with two columns, the first one is for the Name, and the second one is for the ExigenceList attribute. BUT I get a bad table display.
My Html code is :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="max-height: 500px; overflow-y: auto" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th> Exigence Name</th>
        <th> List </th> 
        </tr>




    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in list" style="background-color: #F5F5F5">
        <td rowspan="{{item.ExigenceList.length}}">
            {{item.NomExigence}}
        </td>


        <td data-ng-repeat="subitem in item.ExigenceList track by $index" style="background-color: #F5F5F5">
            {{subitem}}
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Any solution to display the table as i want please ?

Comment: What is the actual javascript structure of `list`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs: use of rowspan to group hierarchical data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104750/angularjs-use-of-rowspan-to-group-hierarchical-data)

Comment: the structure is defined on the begining : 'ExigenceResultDto' class

Comment: @JeremyThille the structure of list is a Collection of ExigenceResultDto

Comment: `public ExigenceResultDto()
    {
        ExigenceList = new Collection<string>();
    }` This is not javascript. This is C# I think, but I don't know C#, and I don't know what it produces exactly. Angular is javascript, parses javascript, and doesn't mind how and with what language that javascript has been produced upstream (and so do I :) That's why I'd like to know the _actual javascript_ structure of list. The one that's being parsed by Angular.