# AngularJS to generate grouped data in a table using RowSpan

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I have the following data structure:

```
data = [{"nums": [1, 6, 5], "name": "John"},
        {"nums": [2], "name": "Bob"},
        {"nums": [9, 6], "name": "Jason"}]
```

And I want it to output to html using ng-repeat as:

```
|------------|
| 1 |        |
|---|        |
| 6 | John   |
|---|        |
| 5 |        |
|---|--------|
| 2 | Bob    |
|---|--------|
| 5 |        |
|---| Jason  |
| 2 |        |
|---|--------|
```

How might I do that?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104750/angularjs-use-of-rowspan-to-group-hierarchical-data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the ng-repeat on tbody and then continue the loop down like this

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="row in data">
    <tr ng-repeat="col in row.nums">
      <td>{{col}}</td>
      <td rowspan="{{$first ? row.nums.length : 1}}" ng-show="$first">{{row.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Se plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/sMmapptIy0Hr0v8riXrs?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{"nums": [1, 6, 5], "name": "John"},
        {"nums": [2], "name": "Bob"},
        {"nums": [9, 6], "name": "Jason"}];
});
```

```css
th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tdcell {
  border:  0px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<table>
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Nums</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat='item in data'>
        <td class="spanRows" rowspan="{{item.nums.length}}">{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='num in item.nums'>
          <td class="tdcell">{{num}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
        </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```